# The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I get the following errors for the same file: LocationToLatLngValueConverter.cs

Reference:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-41-Maps

```
The type `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly `System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.

`D:\MVVMCross\MVVMCrossApps\MAP\Map\Map.Droid\Views\LocationToLatLngValueConverter.cs`

`Map.Droid.Views.LocationToLatLngValueConverter.Convert(Map.Core.ViewModels.Location, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)': no suitable method found to override`

`D:\MVVMCross\MVVMCrossApps\MAP\Map\Map.Droid\Views\LocationToLatLngValueConverter.cs`

`Map.Droid.Views.LocationToLatLngValueConverter.ConvertBack(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.LatLng, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)': no suitable method found to override    D:\MVVMCross\MVVMCrossApps\MAP\Map\Map.Droid\Views\LocationToLatLngValueConverter.cs`
```

According to the demo everything of the application is provided.

I am still unable to get rid of the problems.

Comment: Can you share the code of this value converter?

Comment: @Martijn Yes sure, Here you can download my code: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9qp93i8rr3tab9/Map.rar?dl=0

Comment: I have created the same application form scratch as I have read on xamarin blog that re-coding it resolves the problem, but I am getting following error : is there anything I am missing?

Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type MapTest.Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more information

Comment: You should add your code for the converter to the question itself. In the future the dropbox might not be available anymore, and then others could not look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into the code, and there is actually nothing wrong with that converter. The reason it is failing is that you have references to System.ObjectModel and System.Runtime that point to wrong versions of those classes. You can see that because there is a "red X" behind their names in Xamarin studio.

Also very specific versions of .net and other packages are referenced, which is not advised for normal purposes.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. yes sure I know that there might be a little versioning issue, do u have any suggestion to solve above problem. By the time I have created the same application from the scratch, and it is working fine. but want to know how to hunt this issue.

Comment: You could click with your right mouse button on the wrong references and delete them.

Answer (score 15):

I just had this error in a Unit Test project referencing a PCL. 
It was complaining that I hadn't referenced `System.Object`. The problem seemed to have been due to me referencing `System.Runtime` - Resharper seems to want to add it.

Removing the reference to `System.Runtime` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by removing all using statements at the beginning of the file and then adding them back one by one.

Resharper eventually suggested me to reference `System.ObjectModel`